# Merging SVG files

Tags: svg

So I've got a script that merges SVG files by putting `<svg>` elements into a parent `<svg>` element.

I'm encountering a problem and I'm not exactly seeing the solution. Most of the SVG files are made by drawing them via `<path>` elements.

For some reason I'm not finding a way to combine them in a way that's logical - each `<path>` element seems to have its own position defined by the path and there seems to be no way to bring them into the same "space" so to speak.

Let me give an example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="960" viewBox="0, 0, 1280, 960">
<g id="example_id">
    <path d="M757.55,333.402 L757.851,332.467 L758.381,330.574 L758.829,328.659 L759.216,326.731 L759.726,323.829 L760.216,320.931 L760.566,319.014 L760.755,318.063 L760.753,318.072 L760.776,317.977 L760.835,317.799 L760.968,317.507 L761.222,317.073 L761.555,316.595 L761.959,316.077 L762.423,315.531 L763.204,314.677 L764.331,313.531 L765.183,312.707 L765.734,312.19 L766.257,311.706 L766.738,311.266 L767.167,310.878 L767.53,310.551 L767.684,310.412 L767.684,310.412 C767.687,310.409 767.691,310.406 767.694,310.403 L767.694,310.403 L768.315,309.822 L769.549,308.57 L770.755,307.263 L771.945,305.946 L773.139,304.656 L774.357,303.431 L775.292,302.58 L775.928,302.054 L776.586,301.558 L777.263,301.1 L777.601,300.892 L777.577,300.906 L777.71,300.832 L777.952,300.721 L778.361,300.587 L778.978,300.461 L779.649,300.392 L780.351,300.366 L781.059,300.37 L781.751,300.389 L782.406,300.408 L782.714,300.411 L782.714,300.411 C782.717,300.411 782.719,300.411 782.721,300.411 L782.721,300.411 L783.153,300.405 L784.074,300.379 L784.763,300.387 L785.201,300.425 L785.615,300.499 L785.996,300.618 L786.166,300.696 L786.166,300.696 C786.291,300.751 786.526,300.636 786.69,300.437 C786.854,300.238 786.885,300.032 786.759,299.976 L786.555,299.888 L786.132,299.761 L785.68,299.686 L785.21,299.65 L784.498,299.647 L783.58,299.679 L783.146,299.688 L783.153,299.688 L782.85,299.686 L782.193,299.672 L781.488,299.658 L780.757,299.658 L780.017,299.691 L779.283,299.775 L778.575,299.93 L778.066,300.108 L777.742,300.262 L777.608,300.338 L777.608,300.338 C777.6,300.342 777.592,300.347 777.584,300.352 L777.584,300.352 L777.194,300.596 L776.453,301.104 L775.74,301.648 L775.047,302.229 L774.056,303.142 L772.803,304.414 L771.602,305.723 L770.43,307.033 L769.266,308.308 L768.082,309.522 L767.463,310.107 L767.472,310.098 L767.32,310.237 L766.956,310.569 L766.524,310.964 L766.038,311.413 L765.508,311.909 L764.947,312.443 L764.074,313.298 L762.921,314.486 L762.116,315.382 L761.627,315.97 L761.19,316.541 L760.82,317.089 L760.531,317.601 L760.378,317.957 L760.309,318.177 L760.288,318.27 L760.288,318.27 C760.287,318.273 760.287,318.276 760.286,318.279 L760.286,318.279 L760.108,319.231 L759.786,321.14 L759.344,324.013 L758.889,326.882 L758.544,328.783 L758.143,330.668 L757.663,332.534 L757.387,333.46 C757.387,333.46 757.387,333.46 757.387,333.46 C757.374,333.504 757.399,333.527 757.444,333.511 C757.489,333.495 757.536,333.446 757.55,333.402 L757.55,333.402" fill="#4E413D"/>
    <path d="M752.139,372.053 L751.815,372.552 L751.232,373.574 L750.741,374.617 L750.334,375.672 L750.002,376.739 L749.735,377.815 L749.524,378.901 L749.359,379.995 L749.178,381.647 L749.009,383.87 L748.856,386.109 L748.645,388.354 L748.496,389.471 L748.496,389.467 L748.472,389.622 L748.417,389.965 L748.32,390.554 L748.185,391.443 L748.07,392.404 L748.001,393.388 L747.997,394.113 L748.024,394.578 L748.08,395.019 L748.167,395.431 L748.29,395.807 L748.454,396.142 L748.555,396.297 L748.555,396.297 C748.557,396.299 748.558,396.301 748.56,396.303 L748.56,396.303 L748.706,396.493 L749.024,396.854 L749.371,397.187 L749.741,397.494 L750.331,397.908 L751.169,398.394 L752.041,398.825 L752.919,399.224 L753.779,399.613 L754.593,400.015 L754.973,400.226 L754.971,400.225 L755.104,400.302 L755.408,400.471 L755.755,400.655 L756.139,400.851 L756.77,401.153 L757.685,401.55 L758.643,401.908 L759.363,402.128 L759.834,402.243 L760.29,402.327 L760.729,402.375 L761.147,402.382 L761.545,402.34 L761.758,402.293 L761.758,402.293 C761.772,402.289 761.787,402.285 761.802,402.28 L761.802,402.28 L761.897,402.249 L762.162,402.133 L762.577,401.884 L763.124,401.463 L763.659,400.983 L764.164,400.49 L764.633,400.019 L765.052,399.605 L765.313,399.364 L765.446,399.254 L765.488,399.224 L765.484,399.227 L766.116,398.742 L767.357,397.709 L768.532,396.616 L769.628,395.475 L770.647,394.29 L771.591,393.063 L772.463,391.796 L773.264,390.494 L774.001,389.157 L774.677,387.786 L775.296,386.384 L775.863,384.949 L776.381,383.484 L776.856,381.987 L777.291,380.46 L777.689,378.904 L777.877,378.111 L777.877,378.111 C777.877,378.109 777.878,378.106 777.878,378.104 L777.878,378.104 L778.178,376.758 L778.748,374.063 L779.188,372.061 L779.504,370.744 L779.85,369.441 L780.221,368.159 L780.41,367.534 L780.41,367.534 C780.495,367.291 780.37,367.156 780.131,367.232 C779.892,367.307 779.629,367.565 779.544,367.807 C779.544,367.807 779.544,367.807 779.544,367.807 L779.275,368.49 L778.813,369.842 L778.423,371.191 L778.078,372.543 L777.615,374.565 L777.036,377.255 L776.734,378.602 L776.736,378.594 L776.554,379.366 L776.166,380.889 L775.748,382.376 L775.294,383.826 L774.803,385.237 L774.27,386.609 L773.693,387.941 L773.068,389.231 L772.392,390.479 L771.663,391.685 L770.877,392.849 L770.029,393.972 L769.116,395.055 L768.131,396.1 L767.068,397.108 L765.908,398.091 L765.277,398.582 L765.277,398.582 C765.276,398.583 765.275,398.584 765.273,398.585 L765.273,398.585 L765.152,398.681 L764.936,398.868 L764.62,399.166 L764.19,399.598 L763.749,400.049 L763.313,400.483 L762.908,400.86 L762.549,401.154 L762.324,401.304 L762.19,401.371 L762.095,401.403 L762.139,401.39 L762.022,401.422 L761.701,401.465 L761.329,401.466 L760.921,401.429 L760.484,401.356 L760.029,401.253 L759.321,401.05 L758.369,400.713 L757.453,400.333 L756.821,400.044 L756.437,399.857 L756.09,399.68 L755.786,399.518 L755.651,399.443 L755.651,399.443 C755.65,399.443 755.649,399.443 755.649,399.442 L755.649,399.442 L755.251,399.231 L754.416,398.839 L753.546,398.464 L752.664,398.083 L751.795,397.674 L750.964,397.214 L750.38,396.821 L750.016,396.533 L749.675,396.22 L749.359,395.877 L749.21,395.691 L749.214,395.698 L749.126,395.572 L748.971,395.276 L748.85,394.935 L748.761,394.556 L748.701,394.144 L748.667,393.709 L748.658,393.021 L748.709,392.07 L748.807,391.132 L748.925,390.257 L749.011,389.673 L749.061,389.33 L749.082,389.175 L749.082,389.175 C749.082,389.174 749.083,389.172 749.083,389.17 L749.083,389.17 L749.214,388.045 L749.385,385.813 L749.496,383.6 L749.621,381.411 L749.768,379.79 L749.908,378.722 L750.093,377.664 L750.331,376.619 L750.63,375.586 L751.001,374.566 L751.452,373.56 L751.994,372.563 L752.307,372.063 C752.345,372.003 752.338,371.952 752.292,371.949 C752.246,371.947 752.177,371.993 752.139,372.053 L752.139,372.053" fill="#4E413D"/>
    <path d="M786.357,300.767 L786.486,301.003 L786.731,301.518 L786.962,302.093 L787.181,302.727 L787.388,303.416 L787.583,304.156 L787.768,304.941 L787.943,305.769 L788.106,306.635 L788.259,307.535 L788.471,308.94 L788.724,310.895 L788.942,312.914 L789.129,314.964 L789.289,317.014 L789.425,319.032 L789.537,320.987 L789.632,322.845 L789.691,324.157 L789.727,324.985 L789.76,325.771 L789.791,326.511 L789.819,327.201 L789.847,327.836 L789.861,328.132 L789.861,328.132 C789.861,328.133 789.861,328.133 789.861,328.133 L789.861,328.133 L789.886,328.649 L789.947,329.716 L790.054,331.393 L790.2,333.734 L790.313,336.146 L790.357,338.574 L790.322,340.368 L790.257,341.54 L790.154,342.683 L790.011,343.788 L789.819,344.85 L789.59,345.852 L789.461,346.32 L789.465,346.307 L789.347,346.7 L789.099,347.457 L788.691,348.556 L788.086,349.964 L787.425,351.316 L786.714,352.631 L785.964,353.924 L784.758,355.85 L783.53,357.794 L782.714,359.13 L781.922,360.511 L781.168,361.948 L780.472,363.452 L780.01,364.632 L779.729,365.444 L779.476,366.269 L779.25,367.114 L779.051,367.98 L778.885,368.867 L778.817,369.322 L778.817,369.322 C778.758,369.662 779.017,369.791 779.397,369.611 C779.776,369.431 780.132,369.01 780.192,368.671 L780.28,368.236 L780.468,367.383 L780.673,366.56 L780.899,365.764 L781.143,364.992 L781.4,364.249 L781.817,363.167 L782.408,361.773 L783.05,360.424 L783.738,359.104 L784.461,357.804 L785.594,355.857 L786.739,353.897 L787.508,352.561 L788.247,351.188 L788.941,349.768 L789.574,348.297 L790,347.152 L790.258,346.367 L790.376,345.974 L790.376,345.974 C790.378,345.969 790.379,345.965 790.38,345.961 L790.38,345.961 L790.52,345.446 L790.743,344.403 L790.901,343.325 L791.014,342.21 L791.083,341.066 L791.115,339.897 L791.107,338.11 L791.013,335.702 L790.861,333.31 L790.689,330.985 L790.57,329.319 L790.503,328.259 L790.475,327.745 L790.475,327.746 L790.461,327.451 L790.432,326.817 L790.402,326.128 L790.37,325.389 L790.337,324.603 L790.303,323.773 L790.246,322.458 L790.161,320.592 L790.058,318.627 L789.938,316.596 L789.793,314.53 L789.621,312.464 L789.416,310.428 L789.176,308.456 L788.97,307.039 L788.818,306.131 L788.656,305.256 L788.482,304.419 L788.296,303.624 L788.096,302.876 L787.883,302.177 L787.657,301.531 L787.416,300.943 L787.162,300.418 L787.031,300.184 C786.969,300.072 786.768,300.112 786.582,300.273 C786.396,300.434 786.295,300.656 786.357,300.767 L786.357,300.767" fill="#4E413D"/>
    <path d="M782.236,315 L782.077,315.44 L781.735,316.273 L781.357,317.056 L780.947,317.799 L780.505,318.505 L780.034,319.178 L779.538,319.821 L779.015,320.438 L778.468,321.033 L777.898,321.61 L777,322.453 L775.741,323.533 L774.434,324.58 L773.089,325.619 L771.728,326.668 L770.37,327.748 L769.036,328.878 L768.057,329.778 L767.419,330.411 L766.805,331.063 L766.213,331.743 L765.647,332.452 L765.109,333.193 L764.605,333.967 L764.139,334.775 L763.914,335.203 L763.914,335.203 C763.768,335.486 763.847,335.692 764.091,335.663 C764.335,335.634 764.652,335.381 764.798,335.097 C764.798,335.097 764.798,335.097 764.798,335.097 L764.982,334.739 L765.385,334.025 L765.82,333.342 L766.286,332.687 L766.782,332.056 L767.306,331.445 L767.856,330.853 L768.425,330.281 L769.326,329.441 L770.601,328.348 L771.929,327.28 L773.29,326.217 L774.661,325.141 L776.021,324.031 L777.34,322.872 L778.29,321.96 L778.902,321.32 L779.491,320.657 L780.053,319.97 L780.585,319.255 L781.08,318.514 L781.537,317.743 L781.954,316.944 L782.325,316.113 L782.648,315.255 L782.789,314.821 C782.789,314.821 782.789,314.821 782.789,314.821 C782.842,314.667 782.761,314.582 782.608,314.632 C782.456,314.681 782.289,314.846 782.236,315 L782.236,315" fill="#4E413D"/>
    <path d="M764.173,345.507 L764.411,346.034 L764.93,347.096 L765.461,348.171 L765.965,349.256 L766.39,350.357 L766.633,351.191 L766.746,351.75 L766.817,352.314 L766.84,352.881 L766.81,353.45 L766.722,354.02 L766.657,354.294 L766.662,354.272 L766.565,354.622 L766.332,355.313 L766.046,356.022 L765.71,356.756 L765.334,357.512 L764.921,358.287 L764.25,359.48 L763.303,361.099 L762.352,362.725 L761.669,363.939 L761.241,364.741 L760.848,365.529 L760.496,366.301 L760.334,366.689 L760.334,366.689 C760.324,366.714 760.316,366.739 760.309,366.763 L760.309,366.763 L760.292,366.824 L760.275,367.082 L760.319,367.319 L760.4,367.549 L760.572,367.903 L760.871,368.393 L761.215,368.864 L761.564,369.271 L761.808,369.509 L761.956,369.626 L762.091,369.704 L762.242,369.74 L762.503,369.688 L762.503,369.688 C762.583,369.654 762.667,369.602 762.745,369.537 L762.745,369.537 L762.834,369.464 L763.108,369.187 L763.435,368.749 L763.759,368.209 L764.024,367.773 L764.111,367.665 L764.059,367.73 L764.132,367.645 L764.287,367.478 L764.491,367.271 L764.74,367.025 L765.182,366.605 L765.849,365.993 L766.553,365.368 L767.243,364.777 L767.714,364.387 L767.991,364.165 L768.234,363.979 L768.428,363.838 L768.491,363.795 L768.474,363.807 L768.866,363.551 L769.683,363.029 L770.548,362.483 L771.451,361.91 L772.38,361.308 L773.321,360.672 L774.264,359.999 L775.195,359.285 L776.104,358.529 L776.978,357.726 L777.803,356.874 L778.564,355.969 L779.244,355.012 L779.82,354.006 L780.18,353.213 L780.376,352.67 L780.532,352.133 L780.651,351.588 L780.698,351.304 L780.698,351.304 C780.699,351.299 780.7,351.295 780.7,351.29 L780.7,351.29 L780.765,350.809 L780.874,349.84 L780.948,348.877 L780.99,347.921 L781.002,346.501 L780.915,344.626 L780.719,342.763 L780.425,340.906 L780.045,339.046 L779.588,337.175 L779.333,336.231 L779.333,336.231 C779.333,336.228 779.332,336.226 779.331,336.224 L779.331,336.224 L779.261,335.987 L779.101,335.52 L778.826,334.865 L778.417,334.06 L777.982,333.315 L777.565,332.589 L777.197,331.855 L776.971,331.282 L776.846,330.886 L776.738,330.471 L776.622,330.055 L776.567,329.845 L776.567,329.845 C776.563,329.637 776.346,329.599 776.082,329.76 C775.818,329.922 775.608,330.221 775.612,330.43 L775.567,330.739 L775.529,331.31 L775.57,331.823 L775.656,332.305 L775.846,332.971 L776.172,333.786 L776.553,334.552 L776.949,335.308 L777.342,336.078 L777.609,336.692 L777.767,337.128 L777.84,337.363 L777.838,337.356 L778.102,338.277 L778.587,340.099 L779,341.902 L779.329,343.694 L779.564,345.486 L779.695,347.288 L779.716,348.654 L779.688,349.571 L779.626,350.497 L779.529,351.436 L779.466,351.916 L779.468,351.902 L779.433,352.128 L779.337,352.586 L779.213,353.031 L779.067,353.449 L778.803,354.059 L778.361,354.856 L777.829,355.624 L777.212,356.37 L776.519,357.098 L775.758,357.807 L774.942,358.498 L774.083,359.168 L773.195,359.82 L772.292,360.451 L771.387,361.063 L770.492,361.652 L769.62,362.22 L768.788,362.766 L768.396,363.028 L768.396,363.028 C768.39,363.032 768.384,363.036 768.379,363.04 L768.379,363.04 L768.256,363.126 L768.01,363.308 L767.734,363.525 L767.427,363.776 L766.926,364.197 L766.209,364.82 L765.477,365.476 L764.781,366.121 L764.31,366.572 L764.027,366.851 L763.775,367.111 L763.565,367.341 L763.492,367.426 L763.492,367.426 C763.474,367.447 763.457,367.468 763.441,367.49 L763.441,367.49 L763.242,367.765 L762.966,368.221 L762.742,368.61 L762.621,368.8 L762.565,368.873 L762.477,368.946 L762.719,368.795 L762.918,368.769 L762.895,368.777 L762.803,368.727 L762.679,368.632 L762.454,368.414 L762.12,368.027 L761.79,367.577 L761.506,367.117 L761.35,366.799 L761.284,366.622 L761.25,366.5 L761.235,366.457 L761.252,366.395 L761.227,366.469 L761.368,366.127 L761.695,365.406 L762.066,364.659 L762.473,363.893 L763.14,362.706 L764.09,361.079 L765.047,359.432 L765.732,358.203 L766.161,357.388 L766.556,356.583 L766.909,355.792 L767.212,355.017 L767.453,354.273 L767.546,353.926 L767.546,353.926 C767.547,353.919 767.549,353.912 767.551,353.905 L767.551,353.905 L767.622,353.57 L767.706,352.938 L767.725,352.322 L767.688,351.72 L767.597,351.133 L767.461,350.556 L767.185,349.713 L766.712,348.626 L766.161,347.57 L765.57,346.547 L764.987,345.546 L764.71,345.052 C764.71,345.052 764.71,345.052 764.71,345.052 C764.664,344.962 764.506,344.99 764.358,345.115 C764.21,345.241 764.127,345.416 764.173,345.507 L764.173,345.507" fill="#4E413D"/>
    <path d="M782.228,322.921 L782.351,323.344 L782.629,324.183 L783.099,325.416 L783.761,327.037 L784.227,328.255 L784.501,329.074 L784.621,329.486 L784.619,329.479 L784.661,329.643 L784.747,330.053 L784.841,330.573 L784.944,331.184 L785.052,331.867 L785.17,332.603 L785.362,333.766 L785.643,335.332 L785.866,336.446 L786.019,337.127 L786.173,337.738 L786.326,338.265 L786.482,338.69 L786.643,338.997 L786.732,339.111 L786.732,339.111 C786.756,339.141 786.791,339.157 786.837,339.16 L786.837,339.16 L786.843,339.16 L787.43,338.673 L787.476,338.466 L787.505,338.187 L787.531,337.843 L787.556,337.472 L787.577,337.116 L787.592,336.82 L787.599,336.663 L787.602,336.6 L787.602,336.579 L787.602,336.579 C787.602,336.578 787.602,336.577 787.602,336.575 L787.602,336.575 L787.614,334.155 L787.638,331.728 L787.638,331.73 L787.671,329.712 L787.773,325.732 L787.815,322.767 L787.795,320.787 L787.719,318.799 L787.567,316.8 L787.457,315.792 L787.457,315.792 C787.457,315.79 787.456,315.789 787.456,315.788 L787.456,315.788 L787.444,315.685 L787.407,315.407 L787.354,315.047 L787.284,314.62 L787.195,314.141 L787.085,313.628 L786.883,312.824 L786.631,312.021 L786.434,311.51 L786.216,311.037 L785.976,310.615 L785.711,310.256 L785.42,309.975 L785.094,309.788 L784.811,309.718 L784.59,309.715 L784.458,309.733 L784.458,309.733 C784.437,309.736 784.416,309.741 784.393,309.748 L784.393,309.748 L784.348,309.763 L784.093,309.898 L783.735,310.236 L783.419,310.718 L783.168,311.241 L782.922,311.829 L782.671,312.488 L782.41,313.208 L782.138,313.974 L781.712,315.177 L781.268,316.389 L780.963,317.168 L780.654,317.907 L780.339,318.584 L780.023,319.175 L779.716,319.652 L779.595,319.805 L779.595,319.805 C779.348,320.135 779.332,320.451 779.559,320.512 C779.787,320.573 780.171,320.356 780.417,320.026 C780.417,320.026 780.417,320.026 780.417,320.026 L780.657,319.697 L781.049,319.062 L781.406,318.372 L781.737,317.632 L782.046,316.854 L782.335,316.049 L782.736,314.834 L783.1,313.651 L783.328,312.907 L783.545,312.22 L783.75,311.609 L783.941,311.098 L784.106,310.729 L784.188,310.558 L784.116,310.585 L784.047,310.604 L784.093,310.591 L784.028,310.606 L784.063,310.598 L784.167,310.594 L784.348,310.635 L784.601,310.792 L784.842,311.05 L785.064,311.395 L785.267,311.812 L785.449,312.284 L785.612,312.793 L785.825,313.598 L786.001,314.403 L786.098,314.914 L786.182,315.386 L786.25,315.805 L786.303,316.158 L786.341,316.43 L786.355,316.532 L786.354,316.528 L786.471,317.513 L786.648,319.473 L786.76,321.42 L786.82,323.361 L786.845,326.28 L786.832,330.212 L786.839,332.206 L786.839,332.206 C786.839,332.207 786.839,332.207 786.839,332.208 L786.839,332.208 L786.862,334.606 L786.874,337.012 L786.874,337.008 L786.874,337.019 L786.872,337.078 L786.865,337.231 L786.849,337.524 L786.828,337.876 L786.803,338.241 L786.774,338.571 L786.747,338.814 L786.752,338.845 L787.313,338.421 L787.307,338.421 L787.411,338.469 L787.35,338.395 L787.212,338.116 L787.073,337.705 L786.936,337.181 L786.805,336.564 L786.679,335.874 L786.496,334.74 L786.264,333.143 L786.093,331.966 L785.983,331.223 L785.874,330.535 L785.77,329.917 L785.669,329.387 L785.575,328.962 L785.531,328.799 L785.531,328.799 C785.53,328.797 785.53,328.795 785.529,328.793 L785.529,328.793 L785.398,328.371 L785.106,327.548 L784.611,326.343 L783.905,324.764 L783.39,323.581 L783.076,322.784 L782.93,322.378 C782.93,322.378 782.93,322.378 782.93,322.378 C782.888,322.248 782.697,322.265 782.503,322.414 C782.309,322.564 782.186,322.791 782.228,322.921 L782.228,322.921" fill="#4E413D"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Another might look like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="960" viewBox="0, 0, 1280, 960">
  <g id="example_id_2">
    <g>
      <path d="M676.545,305.557 C683.194,305.093 690.062,305.519 696.613,304.115 C705.157,302.284 713.008,299.482 721.608,302.553 C726.22,304.2 730.565,307.803 734.586,310.484 C735.377,311.011 736.433,312.412 736.438,312.416 C738.582,314.116 731.279,307.102 731.221,306.999 C729.866,304.559 724.533,297.034 722.569,295.463 C721.31,294.455 719.398,293.925 717.883,293.42 C713.925,292.101 707.04,294.244 702.982,294.982 C691.202,297.124 684.63,296.15 675.704,305.076" fill="#612407"/>
      <path d="M676.331,305.941 L677.577,305.868 L680.076,305.771 L682.588,305.709 L685.108,305.65 L687.631,305.564 L690.149,305.418 L692.659,305.178 L694.535,304.919 L695.782,304.699 L696.407,304.573 L696.407,304.573 C696.409,304.573 696.411,304.572 696.414,304.572 L696.414,304.572 L698.005,304.225 L701.153,303.503 L704.252,302.813 L706.55,302.365 L708.073,302.118 L709.594,301.923 L711.115,301.791 L712.638,301.73 L714.166,301.75 L715.701,301.863 L717.245,302.078 L718.802,302.405 L720.374,302.853 L721.162,303.125 L721.155,303.123 L721.585,303.285 L722.432,303.64 L723.272,304.033 L724.106,304.461 L725.348,305.163 L726.983,306.183 L728.589,307.272 L730.17,308.393 L731.725,309.514 L733.253,310.6 L734.008,311.121 L734.003,311.117 L734.152,311.227 L734.449,311.484 L734.75,311.784 L735.041,312.102 L735.305,312.41 L735.527,312.682 L735.655,312.844 L735.719,312.927 L735.764,312.986 L735.788,313.018 L735.793,313.025 L735.793,313.025 C735.804,313.038 735.816,313.051 735.83,313.061 L735.83,313.061 L735.923,313.136 L736.073,313.25 L736.18,313.323 L736.274,313.366 L737.524,312.338 L737.455,312.008 L737.365,311.89 L737.248,311.753 L737.103,311.59 L736.929,311.402 L736.73,311.19 L736.509,310.957 L736.141,310.575 L735.599,310.018 L735.019,309.429 L734.426,308.83 L733.844,308.245 L733.296,307.696 L732.924,307.323 L732.7,307.096 L732.498,306.893 L732.321,306.714 L732.173,306.563 L732.057,306.444 L731.975,306.359 L731.933,306.314 L731.939,306.319 L731.963,306.354 L731.898,306.235 L731.75,305.972 L731.58,305.681 L731.391,305.366 L731.075,304.852 L730.598,304.098 L730.069,303.28 L729.496,302.414 L728.578,301.064 L727.304,299.243 L726.358,297.933 L725.749,297.118 L725.176,296.364 L724.771,295.851 L724.513,295.537 L724.274,295.246 L724.047,294.982 L723.83,294.75 L723.618,294.559 L723.508,294.478 L723.508,294.478 C723.504,294.475 723.5,294.472 723.496,294.469 L723.496,294.469 L723.204,294.337 L722.536,294.12 L721.88,293.884 L721.238,293.639 L720.274,293.303 L719.016,292.907 L718.424,292.722 L718.424,292.722 C718.422,292.721 718.419,292.72 718.417,292.719 L718.417,292.719 L718.034,292.61 L717.197,292.442 L716.299,292.344 L715.355,292.313 L714.376,292.339 L713.37,292.414 L712.345,292.533 L711.31,292.686 L709.757,292.965 L707.727,293.388 L706.267,293.714 L705.344,293.922 L704.47,294.114 L703.654,294.282 L703.273,294.355 L703.278,294.354 L702.729,294.454 L701.658,294.638 L700.105,294.887 L698.123,295.182 L696.232,295.453 L694.421,295.716 L692.678,295.99 L690.989,296.298 L689.343,296.658 L687.727,297.091 L686.129,297.615 L684.535,298.254 L683.328,298.825 L682.514,299.257 L681.704,299.723 L680.888,300.232 L680.067,300.786 L679.237,301.387 L678.399,302.037 L677.552,302.738 L676.693,303.488 L675.822,304.294 L675.371,304.726 L675.371,304.726 C674.992,305.1 674.832,305.561 675.016,305.755 C675.2,305.949 675.656,305.802 676.036,305.427 C676.036,305.427 676.036,305.427 676.036,305.427 L676.418,305.036 L677.195,304.282 L677.961,303.581 L678.717,302.935 L679.465,302.336 L680.206,301.784 L680.942,301.275 L681.675,300.805 L682.407,300.373 L683.13,299.982 L684.228,299.45 L685.719,298.838 L687.24,298.327 L688.798,297.904 L690.404,297.547 L692.068,297.24 L693.8,296.963 L695.607,296.701 L697.503,296.433 L699.495,296.139 L701.059,295.891 L702.138,295.707 L702.686,295.611 L702.686,295.611 C702.687,295.61 702.689,295.61 702.69,295.61 L702.69,295.61 L703.087,295.536 L703.916,295.37 L704.794,295.182 L705.714,294.98 L707.151,294.667 L709.141,294.263 L710.65,294.006 L711.645,293.868 L712.624,293.764 L713.577,293.702 L714.495,293.688 L715.371,293.729 L716.197,293.831 L716.972,294.003 L717.348,294.121 L717.341,294.118 L717.919,294.316 L719.125,294.742 L720.021,295.114 L720.579,295.405 L721.061,295.767 L721.447,296.222 L721.643,296.457 L721.631,296.447 L721.709,296.523 L721.904,296.694 L722.129,296.888 L722.376,297.11 L722.641,297.359 L722.915,297.639 L723.354,298.102 L723.975,298.794 L724.622,299.557 L725.628,300.796 L726.97,302.539 L727.928,303.843 L728.526,304.679 L729.077,305.468 L729.57,306.198 L729.895,306.695 L730.088,306.998 L730.261,307.275 L730.412,307.527 L730.48,307.644 L730.48,307.644 C730.487,307.656 730.495,307.668 730.504,307.679 L730.504,307.679 L730.525,307.704 L730.576,307.755 L730.662,307.84 L730.783,307.958 L730.937,308.104 L731.119,308.278 L731.327,308.476 L731.557,308.696 L731.939,309.06 L732.498,309.596 L733.093,310.167 L733.699,310.751 L734.29,311.326 L734.844,311.868 L735.218,312.239 L735.442,312.464 L735.643,312.668 L735.816,312.848 L735.958,313 L736.065,313.119 L736.126,313.191 L736.132,312.981 L737.374,311.998 L737.37,312.002 L737.284,311.948 L737.14,311.843 L737.045,311.771 L737.082,311.807 L737.08,311.805 L737.055,311.774 L737.007,311.714 L736.939,311.629 L736.803,311.463 L736.57,311.188 L736.291,310.873 L735.98,310.546 L735.651,310.231 L735.322,309.958 L735.169,309.85 L735.169,309.85 C735.168,309.849 735.166,309.848 735.164,309.847 L735.164,309.847 L734.404,309.342 L732.856,308.282 L731.276,307.184 L729.665,306.082 L728.023,305.011 L726.355,304.002 L725.085,303.307 L724.228,302.882 L723.364,302.491 L722.494,302.141 L722.06,301.983 L722.06,301.983 C722.058,301.982 722.056,301.981 722.054,301.981 L722.054,301.981 L721.234,301.711 L719.614,301.272 L718.007,300.956 L716.413,300.754 L714.829,300.656 L713.254,300.65 L711.687,300.727 L710.125,300.878 L708.567,301.092 L707.009,301.358 L704.676,301.833 L701.558,302.553 L698.409,303.299 L696.812,303.658 L696.819,303.657 L696.213,303.784 L694.99,304.009 L693.137,304.281 L690.64,304.539 L688.125,304.705 L685.597,304.812 L683.064,304.891 L680.533,304.973 L678.011,305.091 L676.759,305.173 C676.759,305.173 676.759,305.173 676.759,305.173 C676.583,305.184 676.344,305.365 676.226,305.577 C676.108,305.789 676.154,305.952 676.331,305.941 L676.331,305.941" fill="#431F14"/>
    </g>
</g>
 </svg>
```

Now both of these would be inside a parent SVG element.

However when I look at the file in Safari and Chrome, each of the separate SVG files (now child SVG elements) is on a separate page.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to change/fix it?

Comment: If they are both within a parent SVG you could always just have them in the same SVG. Unless there are reasons you need them in separate SVGs.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.